# How can I check if all elements of an array are identical in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays

I have an array `@test`. What's the best way to check if each element of the array is the same string?

I know I can do it with a `foreach` loop but is there a better way to do this? I checked out the map function but I'm not sure if that's what I need.

Comment: The quality of your solution really depends on what you're doing in that foreach loop. Yes, there are lots of ways to do it, but why do you feel your current solution is lacking?

Comment: Why don't you code and post that "foreach" solution, so we can comment?

Comment: to all the posters concerned about undef, I wouldn't assume "check if each element of the array is the same string" includes the possibility of undefs - a "string" by definition :) is defined. (though it's certainly something to consider)

Comment: Do you just want to know if they are all the same or would you also like to know which ones are different?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the string is known, you can use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) in scalar context:

```
if (@test == grep { $_ eq $string } @test) {
 # all equal
}
```

Otherwise, use a hash:

```
my %string = map { $_, 1 } @test;
if (keys %string == 1) {
 # all equal
}
```

or a shorter version:

```
if (keys %{{ map {$_, 1} @test }} == 1) {
 # all equal
}
```

NOTE: The `undef`ined value behaves like the empty string (`""`) when used as a string in Perl. Therefore, the checks will return true if the array contains only empty strings and `undef`s.

Here's a solution that takes this into account:

```
my $is_equal = 0;
my $string   = $test[0]; # the first element

for my $i (0..$#test) {
    last unless defined $string == defined $test[$i];
    last if defined $test[$i] && $test[$i] ne $string;
    $is_equal = 1 if $i == $#test;
}
```

Comment: Bad. You'll always need to traverse the whole array even if there's mismatch in the first element.

Comment: What I did before I saw this answer was sort the array and check if the first and last elements are the same.

Thanks for the code with the hash. I'm still learning to use map properly.

Comment: @Quick Joe Smith: It's not that my current solution is lacking. I was just looking for different ways to do the same thing, and basically use the shortest code so it looks good :P

Comment: Your solution won't work right if `@test` contains `undef` and empty strings.

Comment: @codeholic: If you use an undef and perl expected a string, perl uses the empty string, "", in its place.

Comment: @codeholic: "Bad" only if the array may be unusually large.  For shorter arrays, grep is the way to go.

Comment: @eugene y: yes, s/he means `grep $_ eq $string, @array` will return a count of elements that are either "" or undef when $string is either "" or undef.

Comment: @eugene You don't know what array size Wireless has.

Comment: @ysth If you can't see my bristle on the avatar, don't call me or anyone s/he anyway. Use the nickname instead. "S/he" is very annoying.

Answer (score 10):

Both methods in the accepted post give you the wrong answer if `@test = (undef, '')`. That is, they declare an undefined value to be equal to the empty string.

That might be acceptable. In addition, using `grep` goes through all elements of the array even if a mismatch is found early on and using the hash more than doubles the memory used by elements of array. Neither of these would be a problem if you have small arrays. And, `grep` is likely to be fast enough for reasonable list sizes.

However, here is an alternative that 1) returns false for `(undef, '')` and `(undef, 0)`, 2) does not increase the memory footprint of your program and 3) short-circuits as soon as a mismatch is found:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

# Returns true for an empty array as there exist
# no elements of an empty set that are different
# than each other (see
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

sub all_the_same {
    my ($ref) = @_;
    return 1 unless @$ref;
    my $cmpv = \ $ref->[-1];
    for my $i (0 .. $#$ref - 1)  {
        my $this = \ $ref->[$i];
        return unless defined $$cmpv == defined $$this;
        return if defined $$this
            and ( $$cmpv ne $$this );
    }
    return 1;
}
```

However, using [List::MoreUtils::first_index](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils) is likely to be faster:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( first_index );

sub all_the_same {
    my ($ref) = @_;
    my $first = \ $ref->[0];
    return -1 == first_index {
        (defined $$first != defined)
            or (defined and $_ ne $$first)
    } @$ref;
}
```

Comment: +1 Interesting answer. I posted a variant on your first method (but please let me know if I overlooked something).

Comment: Um, you really should try your code before posting it. You want 'my $ref = \@_;' in vour sub 'my ($ref) = @_;' is putting the first element or the passed array into $ref.

Comment: @htaccess Exactly ... you are supposed to call `all_the_same` with a reference to the array you are checking as the one and only argument.

Comment: I see, I was passing an array not a ref. Using @_ and not shift suggested it was an array being passed.

Comment: @htaccess On the other hand, assigning to a scalar whose name is `$ref` might be considered sufficient indication that the function expects a ref. Also, note that in the more than four years since I answered the question, you seem to be the only one who is confused about this. For you to assume that I post code without running it is a little ridiculous.

Comment: Yes sorry, I was jumping to invalid conclusions.

Answer (score 4):

TIMTOWTDI, and I've been reading a lot of [Mark Jason Dominus](http://hop.perl.plover.com/) lately.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub all_the_same {
    my $ref = shift;
    return 1 unless @$ref;
    my $cmp = $ref->[0];
    my $equal = defined $cmp ?
        sub { defined($_[0]) and $_[0] eq $cmp } :
        sub { not defined $_[0] };
    for my $v (@$ref){
        return 0 unless $equal->($v);
    }
    return 1;
}

my @tests = (
    [ qw(foo foo foo) ],
    [ '', '', ''],
    [ undef, undef, undef ],
    [ qw(foo foo bar) ],
    [ '', undef ],
    [ undef, '' ]
);

for my $i (0 .. $#tests){
    print "$i. ", all_the_same($tests[$i]) ? 'equal' : '', "\n";
}
```

Comment: I used that one, works perfectly. However it has a tiny flaw.
return unless $equal->($v); should be return 0 unless $equal->($v);

Comment: @user2050516 In the case at hand, it doesn't matter whether we return `undef` or `0` (both evaluate to false).

Comment: till yesterday I had the same opinion but exactly this flaw not returning undef or 0 screwed up.
See below those are two things, undef is a value, nothing is nothing.
  return undef;
  return;
Where does it play a role ? If you do this: @array=(all_the_same([0,1]), all_the_same([1,1])); print @array,"\n"; 
Big suprise it will have one element in the array.

Comment: @user2050516 Point taken. Returning 0 does make the function behave more sensibly in list context.

Answer (score 3):

You can check how many times the element in the array (@test) is repeated by counting it in a hash (%seen). You can check how many keys ($size) are present in the hash (%seen). If more than 1 key is present, you know that the elements in the array are not identical.

```
sub all_the_same {
    my @test = @_;
    my %seen;
    foreach my $item (@test){
      $seen{$item}++
    }
    my $size = keys %seen;
    if ($size == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think, we can use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq)

```
my @uniq_array = uniq @array;
my $array_length = @uniq_array;
$array_length == 1 ? return 1 : return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `List::Util::first` for all similar purposes.

```
# try #0: $ok = !first { $_ ne $string } @test;
# try #1: $ok = !first { (defined $_ != defined $string) || !/\A\Q$string\E\z/ } @test;

# final solution
use List::Util 'first';
my $str = shift @test;
my $ok = !first { defined $$_ != defined $str || defined $str && $$_ ne $str } map \$_, @test;
```

I used `map \$_, @test` here to avoid problems with values that evaluate to false.

**Note.** As cjm noted fairly, using `map` defeats the advantage of first short-circuiting. So I tip my hat to Sinan with his `first_index` solution.

Comment: But what if `@test` contains the empty string (or 0, or `undef`)?  Your test will set `$ok` to true when it should be false.

Comment: But it's not the test that's wrong.  It's the fact that `first` returns the element of `@test` that passed the test.  There's no way to distinguish between an `undef` in `@test` and failure to find a match.

Comment: I've fixed everything. And a regular expression is not required. Though the solution is not very laconic.

Comment: I would have written that `defined($$_) != defined($str) || defined($str) && $$_ ne $str`

Comment: What's wrong?  Well, it kind of showcases the limitations of first() :)

Comment: @ysth Okay, `first` has some limitations. But it shortcuts the loop as soon as mismatch is found as opposed to `grep`. `map \$_, @test` fixes all limitations about `first`. And the heavy condition inside the braces has nothing about `first`. Other answers are just wrong because they don't take `undef` into account.

Comment: The only problem now is that using `map` kind of defeats the advantage of `first` short-circuiting.  But the code actually works, so I removed my downvote.